# Three level selector

Tags: jquery

I was looking around for some jquery plugin but couldn't find any. At picture you can see three level category selector - when user selects first, the other box is manipulated from selected values etc. does anybody knows if there is a plugin like this already made?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are at least 3 **cascading drop down** plugins for jquery on the jquery site

see: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/cascading-drop-downs

update: a few more here http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/drop-down

Answer (score 2):

Look at some of the menus designed for iPhones that use the 'sliding panels of subcategories' concept:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

They're not using select lists, so if that's a requirement, they won't work as-is. But if that's not a requirement, I think any of those will work with some minor CSS tweaks.